# First time parent & child checkbox not checked in treeview kendo ui with angularjs 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, angular1.6

I have integrated Kendo UI v2017.3.1206 (http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui)    treeview with angular 1.6.

I have one strange issue like when i am first time clicking on any parent checkbox its not selecting its children chekboxes and at second time when i am clicking on any parent checkbox its working fine.

I am generating datasource from database based on selected option from dropdown. So when user changes selection from dropdown i am generating new datasource in controller and rebind with treeview.

There are no any javascript errors on my console.

I have below treeview options configured at my controller:

### Code in my controller file:

```
            vm.treeViewOptions = {
                dataSource: formatedDataSource,
                dataTextField: "text",
                checkboxes: {
                    checkChildren: true
                },
                loadOnDemand: false,
                expandAll: false,
                dataBound: function(e) {
                    if(e.node){
                        e.sender.expand(e.node);    
                    }

                },
                check: function(e) {
                    /* Change color to light blue for text if checkbox is checked for treeview */
                    var checkboxstatus = $(e.node).find("input:checkbox").prop('checked');
                    if (checkboxstatus) {
                        $(e.node).find('span.k-in').addClass('selectedItem');
                    } else {
                        $(e.node).find('span.k-in').removeClass('selectedItem');
                    }
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $scope.$apply(function() {
                            vm.selectedPermissionCount = getCheckedItems(e.sender).length;
                        });
                    })
                },
                select: function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
```

### Code in my HTML file:

```
    <div id="treeview" class="float-left bd-x-0 bd-y-0" k-options="vm.treeViewOptions" k-rebind="vm.treeViewOptions" kendo-tree-view="tree">
```

Please let me know if any solutions for this.